YAML azure pipeline: How to get stage names starting with keyword under DependsOn property
My YAML release pipeline has more than 100 stages, and the important stage names start with 'Start_Deployment_****'.
I have a stage at the end that should run after all the above stages have completed. I know I can provide all 99 stage names under the DependsOn property of the 100th stage, and I think that's not a good solution.
Is there any way I can loop through some predefined variable to get the stage names that start with the above string and use them under the DependsOn property of the 100th stage?
(As the values for stage names are available during compile time)
stages:
- stage: Start_Deployment_1
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **
    
- stage: Start_Deployment_2
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **
    
- stage: Start_Deployment_3
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **
.....
.....
.....
- stage: Start_Deployment_99
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **
.....
- stage: DeployToPRod_100
  dependsOn:
  -  // get all above 99 stage names here, maybe using foreach on some predefined variable..
  -
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **


I know I can use deployment jobs for the same kinds of jobs running on different machines, but I can't use Environment VMs in my case. Also, the 99 stages are of different natures, with different jobs running non-similar steps on different machines or pools.

Were the stages added manually or programmatically, e.g. using the ${{ each...}} keyword?

manually.. as they are entirely different than each other executing different steps on different pools.

@osim_ans I'm afraid your requirements cannot be implemented directly in one Pipeline, because there are currently no predefined variables that can contain all previous stages. You may consider splitting the pipeline into two to run the stages and use pipeline resource. Refer to my answer for more details

When you define multiple stages in a pipeline, by default, they run sequentially in the order in which you define them in the YAML file. The exception to this is when you add dependencies. With dependencies, stages run in the order of the dependsOn requirements.
If the stages to run before PROD are generated programmatically (e.g. using an ${{ each ... }} keyword) it's easy to add the dependencies to the final stage.
Example:
parameters:
  - name: environments
    type: object
    default:
      - name: Stage1
        displayName: "Stage 1"
      - name: Stage2
        displayName: "Stage 2"
      - name: Stage3
        displayName: "Stage 3"

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- ${{ each environment in parameters.environments }}:
  - stage: ${{ environment.name }}
    displayName: ${{ environment.displayName }}
    dependsOn: [] # run in parallel
    jobs:
    - job: Job1
      displayName: "Job 1"
      steps:
      - script: echo "This is ${{ environment.displayName }}, Job 1"
        displayName: "Print Message"

- stage: DeployProd
  displayName: "Deploy Prod"
  dependsOn: 
  - ${{ each environment in parameters.environments }}:
    - ${{ environment.name }}
  jobs:
    - job: Job3
      displayName: "Job 3"
      steps:
        - script: echo "This is Prod Stage"
          displayName: "Print Message"

Result:


Thanks for replying! Stages have been added manually. Each stage from 1 to 99 is unique, containing different jobs and steps. So, this approach doesn't work in my case :(
Is there any pre defined variable that contains all the stage names as they should be available during compile time.. ? tbh can't find anything in MS docs..

@osim_ans there is always a way :-) Consider also configuring the dependencies manually, if they don't change that often

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box predefined variables can directly get the name of all previous stages and then loop it in final stage dependsOn field.
In addition, since the dependsOn field needs to be expanded at compile time, we cannot use scripts to set custom variables.

I have a stage at the end that should run after all the above stages have completed.

For a workaround, I suggest that you can split the Pipeline into two.
Pipeline one is used to run all 99 stages and Pipeline two is used to run the final stage. At the same time, you can add the Pipeline resource in Pipeline Two and set the Pipeline complete trigger.
For example:
Pipeline One:
stages:
- stage: Start_Deployment_1
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **
    
- stage: Start_Deployment_2
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **
    
- stage: Start_Deployment_3
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **
.....
.....
.....
- stage: Start_Deployment_99
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **
.....

Pipeline Two:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PipelineOne
    project: DevOpsProject
    source: PipelineOne-CI
    trigger: true

stages:
- stage: DeployToPRod_100
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - script: **

In this case, when the Pipeline One complete(All 99 stages complete), it will trigger the Pipeline two to run the final stage. You don't need to set the DependsOn in the Final stage.
For more detailed info, you can refer to the following docs: Define a pipelines resource and resources.pipelines.pipeline.trigger definition
